# Laravel Nova -> domPDF

Tags: laravel, dompdf, laravel-nova

I am using `domPDF` to print a PDF from a Laravel Nova action. PDF generation and download works. What I can't do is pass the selection of records (`$models`) to the view that generates the PDF.

```
    public function handle(ActionFields $fields, Collection $models)
    {
        $pdf = Pdf::loadView('pdf.attendance.blade.php');
        Storage::put('public/PDF/Attendances.pdf', $pdf->download('save.pdf'));

        return Action::download('http://localhost/storage/PDF/Attendances.pdf', 'Asistencias.pdf');
    }
```

Any idea?

Comment: BTW, side question" do you understand what `localhost` means, right?

Comment: Yes, I know that I have to change localhost to the URL of the .env but at the moment I am testing locally.

Comment: I'm still learning and right now trying to understand how to make custom PDFs in Nova

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's simple:

```
$pdf = Pdf::loadView('pdf.attendance.blade.php', compact('models'));
```